# my tab key behaves strangely in CentOS gnome terminal only in empty shell prompt

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, centos, gnome, gnome-terminal, gnome-shell

In my CentOS 6.7 GNOME desktop, something went wrong while I was trying to show a document to my daughter. I must have pressed some keys by accident.
The strange behavior is, when I press tab key in a terminal, it behaves like I have given 'ls' command. But not exactly the same. See picture [here](https://www.flickr.com/gp/144028366@N03/2584S7).
Judging from the first line '--capturefile=minicom.cap' in the figure above, my pressing tab key is causing my .cshrc file to be sourced(or starting a new shell?).  I guess I've touched something in the keyboard short cut because I found  in the keyboard short cut, 'switch between windows' has been changed to <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> from <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> together with this incident. What could have gone wrong? How can I revert it to original? Please help. (I cannot use tab key when I should..)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: my question was obvious but I clarified it. see my post again. Thanks.